# Overloading with optional parameters causes infinite recursion

Tags: scala, recursion, overloading

```
object Color {
    def apply(r: Int, g: Int, b: Int, a: Int = 255): Color =
        new Color(r, g, b, a)

    def apply(r: Float, g: Float, b: Float): Color =
        Color((r * 255).toInt, (g * 255).toInt, (b * 255).toInt)

}
```

It seems to me that the second apply should execute the first. However, it executes itself. If I were to remove the optional parameter, it works. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: How does it know which one to call when you pass three Ints? Will it choose the more correct one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading the spec correctly, alternatives that need to use a default argument are not considered in overload resolution (6.26.3):

> Otherwise, let C be the set of applicable alternatives which don’t
>   employ any default argument in the application to e1, ..., em.

So you can either explicitly call the 4-argument `apply` method by passing the alpha, or call the `Color` constructor directly.

Actually this also means that your Int overload will never be called when passing 3 arguments, which makes the default argument pretty much useless.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to just call `new Color(...)` directly from the second `apply` method.

I'd also give them both an alpha param.

Comment: I've ended up duplicating `new Color(...)` and replaced the alpha parameter with an overload on both. Accepting the other answer though because it answers my question and points the spec's relevance to my situation.

Comment: Of course :)  I was directly addressing the "Is there a way to work around this?" part